# Share a document

Tags: permissions, sharing

We have a Sharepoint 2013 on premises installation.
We have several departments and each department has a teamsite.
No User has full control. Access Requests Settings has been disabled.
What we would like to do is to give the ability to the users of a particular department to share documents (read or contribute) with a user of another department. As far as I understood the ability to share a document is given by the Permission Level "Manage permissions". If we give to someone the ability to manage permissions he will be able to change his permissions and grant himself "Full access" for the Library which we would like to avoid. 
Thank you in advance for the help
Massimo

Answer (score 0):

Could you please follow the steps mentioned in below article, hope this helps.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/612b2d7c-63c7-4943-b3e2-0fd45c09f9ee/can-you-manage-permissions-without-full-control?forum=sharepointadminlegacy